# Possibility to down-vote marked as duplicate, too broad, not a real question etc

Tags: feature-request

A lot of times after searching I end up in a SO question/answer that really helped me, but are marked as a duplicate etc.

When I click on the duplicate, the question might be the same, but expressed in a more complicated way. That is the reason I ended up in the duplicate in the first place, it had a higher ranking in the search engine!

There is a competition among the answers to a question, but not among the questions themselves. I think there should be a way to down-vote a closing decision. It perhaps can only show the down-votes after a threshold, say 10. If it really helped a lot of users, why close?

Comment: Closed questions can be reopened. What you offer is just way too complicated and complex, for no reason whatsoever.

Comment: Your argumentation makes no sense. You had an easier time in understanding question A, but didn't understand question B (and question A is closed as a dupe of B) ... ok, but how does this make question A not a dupe of question B anymore? This duplication system exists to have multiple questions with different explanations (some easier/harder to understand), but equal answers without duplicating the answers (which makes it harder to maintain them). Thus, what sense would it make to remove the "duplicate" note?

Answer (score 4):

That's kind of by design. The reason duplicate questions are kept, is to act as breadcrumbs pointing at a more 'canonical' question.

> When I click on the duplicate, the question might be the same,

Which is why one question is closed as a duplicate of another

> but expressed in a more complicated way.

Which means the questions and answers cover a different range of skills, and search engine parameters.

> it had a higher ranking in the search engine!

Based on your search query.

You can vote to reopen with sufficient reputation, and theory VTC the *other* question as a duplicate of this. With sufficient people voting, you could more or less make the more complex question a duplicate of the simpler one.

You may also find the other question under "linked" from the master question so finding them isn't exactly hard.